# url rewrite for one domain to https

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I have a IIS server running sites using 2 domains with multiple sites on each.
I'm trying to write a url rewrite rule that only affects the one site
The domains is this

```
*.it.test.com
*.test.com
```

I have tried this rule but it seems to it do not seem to work - maybe I need a wildcard or something in the domian.

I'm trying to hit the subdomains of it.test.com

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern"  pattern="^it.test.com$" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}"  pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
  </rule>
```

A couple of sites names could be this

```
bb.it.test.com
aa.it.test.com
cc.test.com
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Enable FRT and see what's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you choose `patternSyntax="Wildcard"`, the `{HTTP_HOST}` in `conditions` is also use wildcard to match.

[image]

So this is reason why `pattern="^it.test.com$"` match failed. Wildcard is a special sentence, mainly including (*) and (?). **Start with (^) and end with ($) is the usage of regular expressions.**

### **Match fail:**

[image]

Even you change `patternSyntax="regular expressions"`, it will still fail because of **^**. `bb.it.test.com` is not start with `it` but `bb`.

[image]

---

Two solutions.

1. Use regular expressions and set the `pattern="(.*).it.test.com$"`, but it only match `bb.it.test.com aa.it.test.com`. `pattern="(.*).test.com$"` will match both of them.

[image][image]

2. Still use Wildcard but set the `pattern="*.test.com"`.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly - I selected option number 2 and uses the wildcard.
Thank you the the help - And thanks for the very well described answer.